# Problem when requiring 'Qt4' in Ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby, qt4, rubygems, qtruby

I have successfully installed:

- **Ruby 1.8.7-p334**
- **Rubygems 1.7.2**
- **rake 0.9.0**
- **qtruby4 2.1.0 mswin32**

Now the following block of code

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'Qt4'
```

gives me an error:

> C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:926:in `report_activate_error': RubyGem version error: qtruby4(2.1.0 not >= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
>       from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:244:in`activate_dep'
>       from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:236:in `activate' 
>       from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:213:in`try_activate'
>       from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:56:in `require'
>       from C:/Users/nick/Documents/NetBeansProjects/RubyApplication2/lib/main.rb:4

Everything good when requiring just 'rubygems'. My OS is Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you require correct gem name

require 'Qt4' seems like little different as almost all the ruby gem names are in simple letters

isnt your  gem name 'qtruby4' by any chance, if so try

```
require 'rubygems'

require 'qtruby4'
```

HTH

sameera

Comment: Hi, thank you for reply. "Rqequire 'qtruby4'" didn't work, no such gem.